# Setting a default value at the beginning or set it explicitly if no "if" case matches

Tags: java

I have the following code to get an object's name.

```
public String getName(Object... manyVarsToCreateObjectName) {
  String ObjectName = defaultValue;
    if(something...) {
      ObjectName = "object1"
    } else {
      if(somethingElse...) {
      ObjectName = "object2"
    }
  } 

  return ObjectName;
 }
```

There are many if cases that affects the final object name, and a default value that set in the beginning and returned if no if clause matches . My questions are:

1. Should I set the default value at the beginning or explicitly set it if no if case matches.
2. Is it better to return objectName as soon as I find a match, or to assign it to a value and return it at the end.

Comment: it doesn't really matter. It's just a matter of coding style. I personally return as soon as I find the match or return defaultValue at the end if reached.

Comment: If you set the value first you can be setting it twice in the method if any of the If statements match.
If you set the default in an else then you make sure the variable is only set once. It is a mix between preference and if you are bothered about the variable being set twice in some circumstances. Return at the end. Better when you have long methods to debuf when you have 1 return rather than many scattered return statements

Comment: Another option is to declare your local variable to be `final`, guaranteeing that it will be set once and only once.

Comment: I prefer the 'get out as soon as possible' approach - that is - return as soon as you know the result, There's something to be said for doing the easier checks first too - more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to leave a method as soon as I find out that either preconditions are not met, or I have a result, like:

```
public String getName(Object... manyVarsToCreateObjectName) {
    if (!myImportedAssumption) {
        return null;    // or anything signalling invalidity (or even throw)
    }

    if (something...) {
        return "object1";
    }

    if (something else...) {
        return "object2";
    }

    // ...

    return defaultValue;
}
```

To me, this is the clearest possible structure. When debugging, you need not bother if anything else happens in the rest of the method, even when it is long. Understanding is easy, because you do not even need `else` logics. And last not least, it encourages clear design: The method does one thing only, there is no additional computation or messing around with the value determined by the `if` sequence. If possible, I try to use `switch` instead, using the same early-exit style.

Comment: It is not always the clearest structure though, particularly if you've got conditional returns from loops. Though you could argue that there are other design problems there.

Comment: I would ;-) Some people also insist on a method having one `return` statement only, but I do not see pros for such a rule.

Comment: There are two main reasons for that: it supposedly makes it easier to prove your code to be correct (using Hoare logic) and it used to help with resource management in languages where there was no `finally` block or equivalent. More on that [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from). In practice I prefer a two-pronged approach: while verifying the input parameters I look for an early exit, but once we get to the business logic, I try to stick to single returns. Not at the price of introducing several state variables though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this is a code style preference. Personally I've found the following to be easiest to read:

```
public String getName(Object... manyVarsToCreateObjectName) {
    if(something...) {
        return "object1";
    } else if(somethingElse...) {
       return "object2";
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

This way any reader will immediatelly see what is returned in case of a match. And the else if makes the logical structure easier to follow, as compared to an `else { if` nested structure.